# Why doesn't paint() make StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have been wondering: Why doesn't the `paint()` method generate a StackOverflowError?
I know that `paint()` must run repeatedly in the background, but what restricts it to only calling it at a speed which the computer can handle without generating the StackOverflowError?
So that it doesn't repeat `paint()` to the point of using too much memory?

Comment: Which code in the implementation of `paint` do you see as calling `paint` again?

Comment: A stack overflow is (almost always) caused by recersive functions that goes too deep. Calling something over and over will not cause a StackOverflow (but may use up all available CPU; slowing other applications)

Comment: Do you know what is a `StackOverflowError` and what causes it? This has nothing to do with the `paint()` method, unless you override it making an infinite recursive call.

Comment: A poor recursive call would be the most common reason for a StackOverflow error. Look at this to find out more about StackOverflow and its probable causes. 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow occurs only with recursive function

```
void paint() {
    // code ...
    paint();
}
```

Stack:

```
-> stack overflow <-
paint()
...
paint()
paint()
paint()
...
main()
```

But in your case the following is happening:

```
while (true) {
    paint();
}
```

`paint()` is being called always from the same stack frame